# Connecting to Oracle DB with LDAP-Credentials

Tags: oracle, ldap

So I would like to connect to a remote Oracle database from my Linux system using the oraclient 19c on the command line, but whenever I try to connect it sees the realmpart of my username as the server.

For example I want to connect with my username "USER@REALM.DOMAIN" to the database identified by "DB" in my tnsnames.ora, i do `sqlplus USER@REALM.DOMAIN@DB` and of course it complains with `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`, because it thinks "REALM.DOMAIN" is the database.

When I try it without the realmpart like `sqlplus USER@DB` it returns `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`.

How can I pass my username to the client?

Comment: Did you configure the database to use Active Directory?  How? (Just give the URL to the document you followed)

Comment: No I didn't configure it. It's a customers database.

Answer (score 1):

For special usernames, use double quotes.

```
SQL> create user "USER@REALM.DOMAIN" identified by 1;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to "USER@REALM.DOMAIN";

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect USER@REALM.DOMAIN/1
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> connect "USER@REALM.DOMAIN"/1
Connected.
SQL>
```